# css - how do i get text on multiple lines?

Tags: css

how do I get the the text on multiple lines instead of single?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Beskrivelse</h3>
    <div class="well"><?php echo $description ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

picture: [echoed text flowing outside of well (bootstrap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdHsy.png)

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Just use the CSS `overflow` property.

Comment: Just insert a "<br>" tag inside the value of $description...will output as HTML or use the CSS property word-wrap:break-word;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you should use a CSS property called word-break.
Here's a link about it:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Here's a snippet on how this works.

```css
.wrap{
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid thin #AAA;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
    </head>
<body>

 <div class="wrap">
  LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimenbook.Ithassurvivednotonlyfivecenturies,butalsotheleapintoelectronictypesetting,remainingessentiallyunchanged.Itwaspopularisedinthe1960swiththereleaseofLetrasetsheetscontainingLoremIpsumpassages,andmorerecentlywithdesktoppublishingsoftwarelikeAldusPageMakerincludingversionsofLoremIpsum.
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

**try `pre` tag element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.**

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Beskrivelse</h3>
        <div class="well"><pre><?php echo $description ?></pre></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply fix the issue on all pages instead of using the "pre" tag for each division.

Simply add the following css code to your stylesheet file:

```
 html {
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

This will surely fix the problem.